# Python: multiprocessing Pool map with init(pass handler to mapped function), AND uninit

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I want to do something like this using `Pool`:

1. For each process in the Pool, initialize a handler (database handler, http handler, whatever).
2. Call the mapped function with the handler initialized in step 1.
3. Call an uninitialize function with the handler initialized in step 1.

Is that possible with Pool and map, or do I have other better/simpler choices? Should I just write my own multiprocessing.pool.worker()?

here is basically what I want to do:

```
# per worker lifetime 
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost",8080)
# to be mapped, with conn from worker as a arg
conn.request("GET", "/some/url")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
r1.status 
# per worker lifetime
conn.close()
```

Comment: could you post a code snippet showing a sequential implementation of what you want to do, and point out what you want to parallelize?